# Python: How to pass multiple OPTIONAL values to an option using typer

Tags: python, command-line-interface, typer

I am making a cli using `typer`. From the [docs](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/multiple-values/options-with-multiple-values/) I can read that it is possible to pass multiple values to an option but all become required not optional.

Here you can create a parameter that can accept multiple values.(From the [docs](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/multiple-values/options-with-multiple-values/))

```py
def main(user: Tuple[str, int, bool] = typer.Option((None, None, None))):
```

But as you see at the bottom, It shows an error if you don't give 3 arguments

```
python main.py --user Alex 32

Error: --user option requires 3 arguments
```

So how can you make `--user` accept 1 argument as required and make the rest optional.

Comment: Should this always accept *either* 1 or 3 values or anything from 1 *to* 3? What should be the type of the second argument it just two are allowed - can it be `bool`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi All values are mapped to their types. that means the first value must be a string the second an int and the third a bool. So you can't use a string or a bool type for the second value.  And I also noticed i had mismatched the types so I have edited that also

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List` instead of `Tuple`

```
from typing import List, Optional
def main(user: Optional[List[str | int]]):
```

(The Optional here is in case you do not want to pass any value
and then use the script as follow:

```
python main.py --user Alex --user 32 --user 34 --user Harry
```